# How to get Drupal 7 to search attached PDF and Word documents

Tags: 7, search

From what I have read it seems like you have to use Solr to have PDF and Word attachments indexed and returned in a search.  I have Solr working with Drupal but I think I need Tika working on Solr in order to do the document indexing.  There is very little documentation I can find for Tika.  Does anybody know where a good source for this is?  Is there a better/easier way to have search in Drupal index attached documents?

Comment: What version of drupal?

Comment: Drupal 7.  See answer below.  Apache Solr Attachments worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To help you, you've this nice module [Apache Solr Attachments](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_attachments). If you download the module you'll have a README.txt that give you some clues how to help you install and configure Tika.

Comment: I think I looked at that and didn't think it would work with Drupal 7.  It does and was pretty straight forward to install and configure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have used [Search Files](http://drupal.org/project/search_files) before with success, but I think the last time we used it was two years ago.  Note that there are server side requirements for executables to do the searching, and that there isn't a Drupal 7 version available.

Comment: There is now a beta for Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

I discovered [Search File Attachments](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_file_attachments), which has support for both Drupal 7/8 and a variety of file types.